# How to fix "TS2741: Property children is missing"?

Tags: typescript

I'm seeing this error on one of my custom elements:

[image]

> TS2741: Property  children  is missing in type  {}  but required in type  StringChildren

Where `Comment` is

```
export function Comment({children}: StringChildren)
export type FlatString =  string | Iterable<string>
export interface StringChildren { children: FlatString }
```

If I click that "Add missing attributes" button it updates my code to

```
<Comment children={''}>
    Hello &lt; secret comment
    Multi-line {'-->'}
</Comment>
```

And then the error goes away.

So it seems like TypeScript isn't recognizing the contents as being equivalent to the `children` prop. Can't figure out why not.

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    // Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "lib": [
            "ESNext",
            "dom"
        ],
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "jsxImportSource": ".",
        "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/example.tsx",
        "./src/render.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./src/jsx.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Note that I'm **not** using React.

---

Can't repro is *exactly* on TS Playground, but this error is kinda similar: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=9&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwMIQC2hwKMAFAN5oAWmANgCZSkC+AXHAMoxSYoBzPHSYsUASjiUAsACg4CuGhwBnCPWAA6ehAHlaDZqXFzFcFjCRRcKYAHc4AKRUgCxUhQDkcTwGoDoqS+3p4msqxycqCQsHD8MMBQCACGaMDcvPxCIka4lEo5YpwqmYIAPiV8ggDaALpwEbJR4NDwyQBGlanwaPTJKipOLgByEIzpMvKKHV0YcDAQPFV64sWlAgDcco3NMT19A0OuRCRkcKAJKIyDziCj41KmigLA8NVcAJ6E7eqaC0tZAAqyQEtXIkkmZjMFisuE8tzcpxgnieCh2UwUyhQlSQGGg5DAfAAbskEuZgMlGDh6B95hc1ssIaioSokGBEuDmeizP91uCGVlHhioTDrHAAAYAHgAhABaWUAEkoMDoKj+F1Y8oAfOKudtIrIsSU6caALxwSWIjxamjAeg6SUAeitZC1ciAA)

> This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'string | string[]' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.(2745)

How does `string | string[]` require multiple children? Same error with just `string`. That should imply 1 child?

If you look at the compiled output,

```
const test = _jsx(Comment, { children: "hello" });
```

We can see that `<Comment>hello</Comment>` does indeed create a prop called `children` that is in fact a string. So why the error?

---

If you change the TS version to [4.9.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=9&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.9.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwMIQC2hwKMAFAN5oAWmANgCZSkC+AXHAMoxSYoBzPHSYsUASjiUAsACg4CuGhwBnCPWAA6ehAHlaDZqXFzFcFjCRRcKYAHc4AKRUgCxUhQDkcTwGoDoqS+3p4msqxycqCQsHD8MMBQCACGaMDcvPxCIka4lEo5YpwqmYIAPiV8ggDaALpwEbJR4NDwyQBGlanwaPTJKipOLgByEIzpMvKKHV0YcDAQPFV64sWlAgDcco3NMT19A0OuRCRkcKAJKIyDziCj41KmigLA8NVcAJ6E7eqaC0tZAAqyQEtXIkkmZjMFisuE8tzcpxgnieCh2UwUyhQlSQGGg5DAfAAbskEuZgMlGDh6B95hc1ssIaioSokGBEuDmeizP91uCGVlHhioTDrHAAAYAHgAhABaWUAEkoMDoKj+F1Y8oAfOKudtIrIsSU6caALxwSWIjxamjAeg6SUAeitZC1ciAA) then the error message is the same as I posted above:

> Property 'children' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'StringChildren'.(2741)

Comment: `<Comment children=''>` this is how it should be because `typeof {}` is `object ` and your case type of `children` is `string | Iterable<string>` hence `children=''`

Comment: Modify your interface like this and give it a try
`export interface StringChildren { children: FlatString | JSX.Element }`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77421498/edit) the question to include a [mre], including all files and content (also ideally with a link to the reproduction of the issue in the [TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Ndyb0m)). Currently, the code shown has syntax errors and won't compile or run. One problem is that the implementation of the `Comment` function is missing, another is that the `JsxComment` type is missing, etc. We'd like to help, but reproducibility is the initial step toward that end. Include text instead of images. See [ask].

Comment: @Manish Where is the `{}` even coming from though? The `<Comment>` should have the `children` prop the way I wrote it, not be an empty object??

Comment: @jsejcksn Kind of tricky to repro is TS Playground because of that `"jsxImportSource": "."` in the tsconfig, but here's a similar error: https://go.mpen.ca/3akax

Answer (score 0):

The secret is to implement `JSX.ElementChildrenAttribute`. Simply adding this should do the trick:

```
declare namespace JSX {
    interface ElementChildrenAttribute {
        children: unknown  // specify children name to use
    }
}
```

This basically tells TypeScript that the children/contents of the element is equivalent to the `children` prop. The type specified above doesn't seem to matter, it's the key that's important.

This is documented here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#children-type-checking

If TypeScript doesn't pick up on your `JSX` typings automatically, `include` it in your tsconfig, e.g.

```json
{
    "include": [
        "node_modules/@mpen/jsxhtml/jsx.d.ts"
    ]
}
```